# Rails CanCanCan resource abilities based on department

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cancan, cancancan

I have two user types **Admin** and **Normal User**

I have the following departments

- Front Office (eg., id is 1)
- Back Office (eg., id is 2)
- Admin (eg., id is 3)

I have a model named **Entry** which takes *user_id, department_id, customer_id*

**Admin** user has **full control CRUD** over all **departments** and all **entries**

**Normal User** are created for respective department and has CRU control over **entries** of respective department

When I create an **entry** from **Normal User** (eg., id is 2) account I get the correct set of *customer_id, department_id, user_id* in the table. The ability of this user has only one entry can_create_entry(current_user.id, customer_id, department_id) eg., (1, 1, 2) for front office normal user account.

When I create an **entry** from **Admin**(eg., id is 1) account, I get the customer_id, department_id, user_id as (1,1,1) in the table wen i tried to create an entry for Back office department whose id is 2.

When I examined the Ability list for **Admin** user; I found there is a duplicate for entries ability viz.,

```
#<CanCan::Rule:0x0000000b61fd18 @match_all=false, @base_behavior=true, @actions=[:create], @subjects=[Entry(Table doesn't exist)], @conditions={:user_id=>1, :customer_id=>2, :department_id=>1}, @block=nil>

#<CanCan::Rule:0x0000000b61fd18 @match_all=false, @base_behavior=true, @actions=[:create], @subjects=[Entry(Table doesn't exist)], @conditions={:user_id=>1, :customer_id=>2, :department_id=>2}, @block=nil>

#<CanCan::Rule:0x0000000b61fd18 @match_all=false, @base_behavior=true, @actions=[:create], @subjects=[Entry(Table doesn't exist)], @conditions={:user_id=>1, :customer_id=>2, :department_id=>3}, @block=nil>
```

And for **Normal User** I have only one entry

```
#<CanCan::Rule:0x0000000b61fd18 @match_all=false, @base_behavior=true, @actions=[:create], @subjects=[Entry(Table doesn't exist)], @conditions={:user_id=>2, :customer_id=>2, :department_id=>1}, @block=nil>
```

Kindly help me fix the issue for admin role.

**Edited:**
*ability_base.rb*

```
class AbilityBase
  include CanCan::Ability
  ...
  def can_read_entries(customer_id, department_id)
    can :read, Entry, :customer_id => customer_id, :department_id => department_id
  end

  def can_create_entries(customer_id, department_id,user_id)
    can :create, Entry, :customer_id => customer_id, :department_id => department_id, :user_id => user_id
  end

  def can_update_entries(customer_id, department_id, user_id)
    can :update, Entry, :customer_id => customer_id, :department_id => department_id, :user_id => user_id
  end

  def can_destroy_entries(customer_id, department_id)
    can :destroy, Entry, :customer_id => customer_id, :department_id => department_id
  end
  ...
end
```

*user_ability.rb*

```
class UserAbility < AbilityBase
  def initialize(current_user)
    if current_user
       user_department_type_names = {}
       @customer = current_user.customer
       @user_type = current_user.user_type
       current_user_dept = current_user.departments           
       @user_department_ids = current_user_dept.collect(&:id)
       @user_department_type_ids = current_user_dept.collect { |dept| 
          dept_type = dept.department_type
          user_department_type_names["#{dept_type.type_name}"] = dept.id
          dept_type.id
       }
       ...
       if user_department_type_names.has_key?("FRONT_OFFICE")
         dept_id = user_department_type_names["FRONT_OFFICE"]
         if @user_type == "NORMAL_USER"
            can_read_entries(customer.id, dept_id)
            can_create_entries(customer.id, dept_id, user_id)
            can_update_entries(customer.id, dept_id, user_id)
         elsif @user_type == "ADMIN"
            can_read_entries(customer.id, dept_id)
            can_create_entries(customer.id, dept_id, user_id)
            can_update_entries(customer.id, dept_id, user_id)
            can_destroy_entries(customer.id, dept_id)
         end
       elsif user_department_type_names.has_key?("BACK_OFFICE")
         dept_id = user_department_type_names["BACK_OFFICE"]
         if @user_type == "NORMAL_USER"
            can_read_entries(customer.id, dept_id)
            can_create_entries(customer.id, dept_id, user_id)
            can_update_entries(customer.id, dept_id, user_id)
         elsif @user_type == "ADMIN"
            can_read_entries(customer.id, dept_id)
            can_create_entries(customer.id, dept_id, user_id)
            can_update_entries(customer.id, dept_id, user_id)
            can_destroy_entries(customer.id, dept_id)
         end
       elsif user_department_type_names.has_key?("ADMIN")
         dept_id = user_department_type_names["ADMIN"]
         if @user_type == "NORMAL_USER"
            can_read_entries(customer.id, dept_id)
            can_create_entries(customer.id, dept_id, user_id)
            can_update_entries(customer.id, dept_id, user_id)
         elsif @user_type == "ADMIN"
            can_read_entries(customer.id, dept_id)
            can_create_entries(customer.id, dept_id, user_id)
            can_update_entries(customer.id, dept_id, user_id)
            can_destroy_entries(customer.id, dept_id)
         end
       end
       ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: where is your userability.rb file? add it to the question

Comment: have edited accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I use a bit different approach for this:

```
class UserAbility
  include CanCan::Ability

attr_accessor :user

def initialize(user)

@user = user

can :read, Entry, do |entry|
  is_admin || (is_normal_user && Entry.where(id, entry.id, customer_id: @user.customer_id, dept_id: user.departments.ids).exists?
end

private

def is_normal_user
  user.user_type == 'NORMAL_USER'.freeze
end

def is_admin
  user.user_type == 'ADMIN'.freeze
end

end
```

of course it's only a template

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will try this. The problem I have is when we create an entry record, the record should have the respective department id. For normal user, there will be one department assigned to him; No problem here. For admin multiple departments will be assigned; so, multiple department ability records gets loaded. And when admin creates an entry record, always cancan assigns the first department id in the ability list not the one i intended to do.

Comment: when you create an entry you need to pass dept_id and customer from user record.

Comment: you shouldn't use cancan for record creation.

Comment: if you are an admin, just show it's deps list as an option in the form.

Comment: Noted your reply. Thanks